# What's the problem between Peter and the giant chicken?

Tags: plot-explanation, family-guy

I have watched a few random episodes of family guy and in some of them Peter fights a giant yellow chicken. This seems to be a joke they repeat in multiple episodes and in one of them I think the fight went on for around 10 or 15 minutes. What is exactly the problem between them? To me it just looks like they just saw each other and started fighting. Is there any episode that explains how it started, and why it has been going on for so long? Is the chicken just another regular resident of Quahog? I know there is a crossover episode with the Simpsons where Peter fights Homer. Is the chicken fight some kind of Simpsons reference?

Comment: https://familyguy.fandom.com/wiki/Ernie_the_Giant_Chicken , https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Ernie_the_Giant_Chicken , etc.

Answer (score 3):

According to a flashback in [Da Boom](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0576925/?ref_=ttep_ep3), the fight started because the chicken handed Peter an expired coupon. The scene can be seen in [this YouTube clip](https://youtu.be/xrziHnudx3g?t=15).

In [Meet the Quagmires](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0945076/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), it is revealed that Peter actually started the fight when he traveled back in time.

[The Simpsons Guy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3065100/) features a similar fight between Peter and Homer. However, I have not seen any evidence to indicate that any of the other chicken fights are any kind of Simpsons reference.

This question was also asked on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Peter-Griffin-fight-the-chicken).

Comment: Why did you post the same answer twice and then delete one of them?

Comment: @F1Krazy browser issue made it seem that the first answer was deleted (it wasn't).

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the chicken is yellow, or has there been any indication that it is a Simpsons reference?

Comment: @F1Krazy FYI, the issue that Raj encountered may be related to [Editing a post leads to a weird behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375054/562482) as it also sometimes occurred when posting. Although this was apparently fixed shortly before this answer was posted, if Raj still had the browser on that question from before the fix was implemented, then it still wouldn't have worked properly.

Comment: @user13267 Yellow is a common color for depicting chickens. In real life, yellow is more of a chick color than one of adult chickens, but adult color schemes tend to be more complex than many animators want to deal with.

Comment: It's worth noting too perhaps, that their first fight scene (and I suppose all subsequent ones) I'm almost positive is a reference to the long fight scene from [*They Live*](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=c9rrgJXfLns)